# Image save issue in custom album as well as default Camera Roll in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, photo-gallery, alassetslibrary

I want to save image in `Custom Album` from my App. i know it possible in `iOS 5` and up.

i am done with this functionality with the [reference link](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/)

From the reference link image save successfully in `Custom Album` but issue is that image `Save in Custom Album as well as Camera roll` . How can i ignore to save in Two folder ?

any one have idea about that ? Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: The reference link doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Yup, now it seems to be working. Looking at it now.

Comment: My apologies, I initially thought you were trying to save the images to a custom folder, but you are saving it to a custom album. I don;t think Apple allows users to have an image in a custom album without having it in the camera roll.